# Creating content string for Google Maps infobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am building a content string for displaying inside a Google Maps infobox but i'm not getting the correct output:

My code:

```
    // Create HTML string for infobox
    var contentString = '<h1>' + park.name + '</h1>' +
      '<p>At ' + park.name + ' there were:</p>' +
      '<ul>' +
        $.each(cars, function(index, value) {
          console.log(value.name);
          '<li>' + value.name + '</li>'
        });
      '</ul>';
```

The console.log gives me the actual name but, the content I outputted in the `<li>`'s I just get:

> [object Object]

Any ideas?

Comment: It's an object you'll have to choose which bit of it you want for it to display correctly, the console should tell you as you'll be able to fold out the object but it will be something like value[index].name

Comment: But why is this working then: console.log(value.name); ?

Comment: console.log will print out values, arrays, functions, objects - what ever you pass it really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a string with a loop in it like this. 
You need to split it up and append the value's to `contentString` within the loop like:

```
var contentString = '<h1>' + park.name + '</h1>' +
    '<p>At ' + park.name + ' there were:</p>' +
    '<ul>';

$.each(cars, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value.name);
    contentString += '<li>' + value.name + '</li>'
});

contentString += '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks. I did think I might be going down the wrong track. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing cars is some sort of array/JSON so you would need to iterate over it.

Assuming your JSON looks like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"cars": [{"value":"Ford"}, {"value":"VW"}, {"value":"Audi"}]}');
```

You would do something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<data["cars"].length;i++) {
    $("#list").append('<li>' + data["cars"][i]["value"] + '</li>');
}
```

Here's a fiddle with in working:

http://jsfiddle.net/CeDsM/